# What is "the product of the digits of n"?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In 2005 Indonesia MO Problems/Problem 2, they say

"For an arbitrary positive integer $n$, define $p(n)$ as the product of the digits of $n$ (in decimal). Find all positive integers $n$ such that $11 p(n)=n^2-2005$."

What is "the product of the digits of n"?

Comment: For example, $p(523)=5\cdot2\cdot3=30$.

Comment: Like “casting out 9s” but multiplying. For example, the product of the digits of $44312$ is $4\times 4\times3\times1\times 2=96$.

Comment: @AndrewChin If threre is 0, for example 109, p(n) will be 0. Is it right?

Comment: Yes if there is a $0$ in it then it will be $0$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Thanks a lot.